# SnackBar displayed only the first time when dispatch an action mutiple times

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, material-ui

I have a snackBar which displays an error or success message according to the dispatched action. I tried to put wrong user credentials in order to test it and submit the form mutliple times but the snackBar appears only the first time.

SnackBar.tsx:

```
import { green } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Snackbar from "@material-ui/core/Snackbar";
import SnackbarContent from "@material-ui/core/SnackbarContent";
import { makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CheckCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckCircle";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import ErrorIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Error";
import clsx from "clsx";
import React from "react";

const variantIcon = {
  error: ErrorIcon,
  success: CheckCircleIcon,
};

const useStyles1 = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  error: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.error.dark
  },
  icon: {
    fontSize: 20
  },
  iconVariant: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    opacity: 0.9,
  },
  message: {
    alignItems: "center",
    display: "flex",
  },
  success: {
    backgroundColor: green[600]
  },
}));

export interface IProps {
  className?: string;
  message?: string;
  onClose?: () => void;
  variant: keyof typeof variantIcon;
}

function MySnackbarContentWrapper(props: IProps) {
  const classes = useStyles1();
  const { className, message, onClose, variant, ...other } = props;
  const Icon = variantIcon[variant];

  return (
    <SnackbarContent
      className={clsx(classes[variant], className)}
      aria-describedby="client-snackbar"
      message={
        <span id="client-snackbar" className={classes.message}>
          <Icon className={clsx(classes.icon, classes.iconVariant)} />
          {message}
        </span>
      }
      action={[
        <IconButton
          key="close"
          aria-label="close"
          color="inherit"
          onClick={onClose}
        >
          <CloseIcon className={classes.icon} />
        </IconButton>
      ]}
      {...other}
    />
  );
}

interface IProps1 {
  open: boolean;
  handleClose: () => void;
  variant: any;
  message: string;
}
export default function CustomizedSnackbars(props: IProps1) {
  const { open, handleClose, variant, message } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{
          horizontal: "left",
          vertical: "bottom",
        }}
        open={open}
        autoHideDuration={6000}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MySnackbarContentWrapper
          onClose={handleClose}
          variant={variant}
          message={message}
        />
      </Snackbar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

SignInContainer.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import SnackBar from "../../components/common/SnackBar";
import SignInForm from "./SignInForm";

interface IProps {
  message: string;
  variant: string;
}
const SingInContainer = (props: IProps) => {
  const { message, variant } = props;
  const [open, setSnackBarState] = useState(!!variant);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSnackBarState(!!variant);
  }, [variant]);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setSnackBarState(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <SnackBar
        open={open}
        handleClose={() => {
          handleClose();
        }}
        variant={variant}
        message={message}
      />
      <SignInForm />
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  const { variant, message } = state.snackBar;

  return {
    message,
    variant,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SingInContainer);
```

What's wrong with this code and how can I display the snackbar everytime that there is a message to be displayed?

Comment: Where are your actions being dispatched?

Comment: You are relying on the `useEffect` to open the SnackBar - and it is only called again when `variant` changes. Since you are showing an error message I imagine most  of the time the `variant` is the same (thus no more `useEffect` calls during this component's life time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation I used [Effects with Cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)
to reset the `variant`in order to update the `snackBar`message.
SignInContainer.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { resetAlert } from "../../actions/ui/snackBarActions";
import SnackBar from "../../components/common/SnackBar";
import SignUpForm from "./SignUpForm";

interface IProps {
  message: string;
  variant: string;
  resetAlert: () => void;
}
const SingUpContainer = (props: IProps) => {
  const { message, variant } = props;
  const [open, setSnackBarState] = useState(!!variant);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSnackBarState(!!variant);

    return function cleanUp() {
      resetAlert();
    };
  }, [variant]);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setSnackBarState(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <SnackBar
        open={open}
        handleClose={() => {
          handleClose();
        }}
        variant={variant}
        message={message}
      />
      <SignUpForm />
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  const { variant, message } = state.snackBar;

  return {
    message,
    variant,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { resetAlert })(SingUpContainer);
```